# Set link href as URL with AJAX .load menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when i click on this menu links i get it on my div, but how can i also set a URL variable so if i click `<a href="admin.php">` i get my new url www.foo.com/**admin.php** i just see the load. if i access directly  www.foo.com/**admin.php** i should get the index.php loading this admin.php and doing the process again, so my admin should also redirect when coming direct at it, someone help me with the way to set the URL with AJAX

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$("#page-inner").load(pathname+'dashboard.php');
$('#main-menu a').on("click", function (e) {
if (this.href .indexOf('#') == -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#page-inner").load(this.href, function () { 
        }).hide().fadeIn('fast');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Could you try to explain it better and show a bit more code?

Comment: Not without reloading. Use the .hash instead so you get  www.foo.com/#admin.php - have a look at the jQuery history plugin